# PowerPC load method address from known address in memory and call the method

Tags: c, powerpc

I am having a MPC5668G here. From an asm code in the bootloader I want to jump to the main routine of the main programm which are generated independently. Therefore I used some pragmas and the linker to put the adress of the main method (wherever it is linked to) to the end of the internal flash. That would be 0x001FFFFC.

How I am trying to call this main method.

I think I am just missing something, but somehow the load instruction fails... or does something wrong.

I am doing this:

```
e_lis  r0, 0x001F
e_or2i r0, 0xFFFC
e_lwz  r3, 0(r0)
```

I can see the registers and the memory, everything looks fine, but

```
e_lwz  r3, 0(r0)
```

just loads FFFFFFFF into r3 (instead of 0x80810 which is the address of main and the value in the memory at address 0x001FFFFC).

Any idea why?

Second question, how to call the the method then?

The BAM of the MPC5668G uses the LR register and blr to branch to the startupcode... Is that the right way to do it?

The original code (as the startup code and the main routine where still linked together) used

```
e_bl main
```

to call main directly.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [PowerPC User Instruction Set Architecture Book 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-archguide-v2.html), lwz is defined as:

```
lwz RT,D(RA)
```

The text for lwz says:

> Let the effective address (EA) be the sum (RA|0)+ D. The word in
>   storage addressed by EA is loaded into RT32:63. RT0:31 are set to 0.

The text, in particular, "RA|0" is basically saying that if the value RA is zero, it is not treated as register 0, it is treated as the value zero. Otherwise, it is treated as the numbered register. This is an important thing to know for any load instruction that uses "RA".

This is further elaborated upon in the Definitions and Notations:

> (RA|0) means the contents of register RA if the RA field has the value
>   1-31, or the value 0 if the RA field is 0.

So, replace r0 with another register in your example to fix the problem.

Comment: Not only useful, also explained. I saw the text in the architecture book, but I didn't get the clue about (RA|0).(I asked a guy at Freescale, he was also surprised over this behaviour.) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The register `r0` always has the value zero when used as the base for a relative load or store operation (there is no opcode for load/store with absolute address). Thus, the `lwz` instruction uses the wrong address.

Use a different register, and it should work.